# Rails geocoder gem geocoding using a custom address format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geocoder

I am using geocoder to get latitude and longitude from address

In model I added

```
class Clinic < ApplicationRecord
    geocoded_by :full_street_address
    after_validation :geocode

    def full_street_address
      [address_line1, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')
    end
end
```

and client has provided me addresses like this

```
{
    "name": "Bahrain Defence Force Royal Medical Services Hospital - Riffa",
    "address_line1": "West Riffa P O Box 28743",
    "country": "Bahrain",
    "state": "Al-Wusta",
    "city": "Riffa"
}
```

Now when I create a clinic its not returning latitude and longitude,

Seems that issue is with address and than with following line

> [address_line1, city, state, country].compact.join(', ')

Is there a way I can specifically provide zipcode etc or how to handle above address?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you followed the Geocoder documentation and added the `longitude` and `latitude` attributes to your model, I tried your code, you just need to add `after_validation :geocode` or use the method `:geocode` in any callback you want.

**EDIT:**

Okay so I think I didn't refresh the page by the time your question was updated, but I tried the exact same code and it worked as expected.

Comment: after_validation :geocode is already in model, I updated question.

issue id with handling address, have you tried address I provided?

Comment: Yes, I used the same data and it gave me back the coordinates, have you tried any other addresses?

Comment: yes, I tried a few address from Pakistan and they are working.

Comment: you changed "full_street_address" method or used as it is

Comment: I kept the code as it's, just added the after_validation because it wasn't there, I had a similar issue before but it was related to the lookup service, which one are you using?

Comment: even google not able to understand state "Al-Wusta" & address_line1, can't understand that how it worked for you.